# How to read a multi-line text file

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to read a text file and output its content into a struct. (I'm trying to output the contents first, instead of going for the structs right away).

I've tried to read a file, but it doesn't seem to recognize the name, even though they are the same and the file exists.

Text file ("settings.txt")

```
vida 3
vel_bola 1
vel_barreira 1
tamanho 15
quant_tijolos 30
tipo_tijolo 1
vel_brinde 1
tipo_brinde 1
tempo_brinde 60
prob_normal 70
prob_resist 20
prob_magico 10
sound 1
```

My code so far

```
int _tmain(int argc, LPTSTR argv[]) {

#ifdef UNICODE
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_WTEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT);
#endif

    //jogo j;

    HANDLE hFile;
    byte buffer[BUFFERSIZE] = { 0 };
    DWORD nIn = 0;

    LPCWSTR fName = TEXT("settings.txt");

    hFile = CreateFile(fName, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Error opening the file %s!\n\n"), fName);
    }else
        _tprintf(TEXT("File %s Open!\n\n"), fName);

    if (ReadFile(hFile, buffer, BUFFERSIZE - 2, &nIn, NULL) == FALSE) {
        _tprintf(TEXT("It wasn't possible to read the file %s\n\n"), fName);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return -1;
    }

    if (nIn > 0 && nIn <= BUFFERSIZE - 2) {
        buffer[nIn] = TEXT('\0');
    }

    _tprintf(TEXT("%s", buffer));   

    return 0;

}
```

EDIT:
Structure to use

```
typedef struct Jogo {

    unsigned vidas;
    unsigned vel_bola;
    unsigned vel_barreira;
    unsigned tamanho_barreira;
    unsigned quant_tijolos;
    unsigned tipo_tijolo;
    unsigned vel_brinde;
    unsigned tipo_brinde;
    unsigned tempo_brinde;
    unsigned prob_normal;
    unsigned prob_resist;
    unsigned probm_magico;
    BOOL sound;

}jogo;
```

I expected the contents to print out in the screen like the text file, but it just gives me a null result (from the debug).

UPDATE: Now it reads the file and puts everything in the buffer, but it still doesn't print out to the screen.

UPDATE END

UPDATE2: It works the way intended, now it's a matter of putting it to a structure.

UPDATE2 END

Comment: Do you mean you could not *open* the file? Try using the full pathname.

Comment: @WeatherVane it does open the file, and puts everything into the buffer, but it just isn't showing. I'm updating with some changes i made

Comment: Try adding a newline to flush the output buffer (although this should happen when the program terminates).

Comment: @JohnnyMopp adding it where? before the final return?

Comment: I asked that because of the question's second paragraph: "it doesn't seem to recognize the name, even though they are the same and the file exists"

Comment: @WeatherVane i updated that it recognises
@JohnnyMopp now it just shows `(null)`

Comment: The `_tprintf(TEXT("%s", buffer));` does not look right. I suggest `_tprintf(TEXT("%s"), buffer);` or even just `_tprintf("%s", buffer);`

Comment: @WeatherVane that worked... Can't believe that was the error..

Comment: The text file content may be ASCII or UNICODE.  Will this work regardless of the text file content?  You might need to check for a UNICODE marker at the start of the file to determine if the input is single or multi-byte characters.  Search online for "byte order mark" to learn more.

Comment: @SteveValliere the file isn't supposed to be modified apart from the values, i believe there's no need to check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reading file with Windows File Api, you could also use the stream method:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>  

#include <iostream>  
#include <tchar.h>
using namespace std;
#define BUFFERSIZE 1024
typedef struct Jogo {

    unsigned vidas;
    unsigned vel_bola;
    unsigned vel_barreira;
    unsigned tamanho_barreira;
    unsigned quant_tijolos;
    unsigned tipo_tijolo;
    unsigned vel_brinde;
    unsigned tipo_brinde;
    unsigned tempo_brinde;
    unsigned prob_normal;
    unsigned prob_resist;
    unsigned probm_magico;
    BOOL sound;//BOOL is defined as int;

}jogo;
int _tmain(int argc, LPTSTR argv[]) {

#ifdef UNICODE
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_WTEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT);
#endif

    jogo j;
    unsigned int arr[13] = { 0 };
    char memmber[BUFFERSIZE] = { 0 };
    ifstream OpenFile("settings.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        OpenFile >> member;
        OpenFile >> arr[i];
        _tprintf(TEXT("%s %d\n"), member,arr[i]);//Also need to ensure the order in .txt file is the same as the struct members.
    }
    memcpy(&j, arr,sizeof(arr));//Since the memory of struct members is the same as arry, so we can convert it with memory copy.

    return 0;

}
```

UPDATE:

Use C Library Function `sscanf`(after you've got buffer from the file):

```
...
_tprintf(TEXT("%s"), buffer);
char temp[20] = { 0 };
sscanf_s(buffer,"%s %d %s %d %s %d %s %d %s %d %s %d %s %d %s %d %s %d %s %d %s %d %s %d %s %d",temp,&j.vidas,temp,&j.vel_bola, temp, &j.vel_barreira, temp, &j.tamanho_barreira, temp, &j.quant_tijolos, temp, &j.tipo_tijolo, temp, &j.vel_brinde, temp, &j.tipo_brinde, temp, &j.tempo_brinde, temp, &j.prob_normal, temp, &j.prob_resist, temp, &j.probm_magico, temp, &j.sound);
```

Comment: @F.Dinis C library function `sscanf(buf,"format",)` could also achieve results. See the update.

Answer (score 1):

The `TEXT` macro probably does not understand the comma in

```
TEXT("%s", buffer)
```

so I would use

```
_tprintf(TEXT("%s"), buffer);
```

or just

```
_tprintf("%s", buffer);
```

both of which keep the arguments for `_tprintf` separate.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the error, the question still remains on how to put the values into a structure, any idea on how to start that?

Comment: If yours is a text file I would abandon the idea of of doing a binary read into a single buffer, and use text-based functions. For example, a line-based reading function like `fgets`, and then analyse what is in each line.

Comment: so the code i have so far isn't right to do a single line to a value in the struct?

Comment: The lines do not have a fixed length, so it's not helpful trying to read a fixed length into a buffer, which may be less than, or more than, one line. `fgets` will read the file line by line.

Comment: Well open the file as a stream. Don't be slave to windows functions and macros.